# How to upload file with the ajax call in ColdFusion .cfc function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, coldfusion

I would like to know if I can upload the file using ajax combined with coldfusion function on the .cfc page? I have created my ajax call in JQuery and I have function on .cfc page but I'm getting weird ajax response after the call. Here is my code:

```
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" method="POST">
  <table role="presentation">
    <tr>
        <td>Order:
            <select name="order" id="order">
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>    
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User ID: 
            <select id="userID" name='userID'>
               <option value='0567'>0567</option>
               <option value='0568'>0568</option>
               <option value='0569'>0569</option> 
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td>File for upload:   
          <input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" onChange="fileSubmit()"/>
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Ajax Call:

```
function fileSubmit(){
   var myForm = new FormData(document.getElementById('myForm'));

   $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'FileUpload.cfc?method=fileUpload',
      data: new FormData($('#myForm')[0]),
      async: false,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
      processData: false,
   }).done(function(obj){
      //I want to check for the status here
      // something like this 
      //if(obj.STATUS === 200){
      alert(obj);
   }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
      alert(errorThrown);
   })
}
```

FileUpload.cfc page:

```
<cfcomponent>
    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="yes" showdebugoutput="no">
    <cffunction name="fileUpload" access="remote" output="true">
        <cfargument name="order" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="userID" type="string" required="yes">
        <cfargument name="fileUpload" type="string" required="yes">

        <cfset fncResults = StructNew()>

        <cfif arguments.order NEQ '' and arguments.userID NEQ ''>
            //Here is my file upload and I'm setting status of 200
            <cfset fncResults.status = "200">
        <cfelse>
            <cfset fncResults.status = "400">
            <cfset fncResults.message = "Invalid access attempt">
        </cfif>

        <cfreturn fncResults>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

My response message that is outputted in `alert(obj)` looks like this:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><struct><var name='STATUS'><string>200</string></var></struct></data></wddxPacket>
```

I'm wondering how I can check for the STATUS of 200 in this case? Usually everything that I returned in the past to the page was JSON format.  If anyone can help with this problem please let me know.

Comment: Maybe you should serialize the return JSON format values using serializeJSON() in coldfusion then check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to 'check' for status 200, as `.done()` only fires on success, ie status code 200.

Comment: So what you are saying is if I can access alert() in .done() that means that my call was successful?

Comment: Yes. But, it depends on the version you are using. You might need to use `.success()` instead. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/